# How to bring back Photo Viewer in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-photo-viewer

In Windows 10, when opening images, it gives me the option to open in the Photos metro app, Paint, or GIMP.

I'd like it to open in Photo Viewer, but when I directed "Open with" to PhotoViewer.dll in "C:/Program Files/Windows Photo Viewer", or "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Photo Viewer", I get a "This app can not run on your PC" error.

I know I could use Irfanview or the sort, but I'd prefer to be able to use Photo Viewer. Is there any way I can bring it back?

Comment: @Ramhound The question makes perfect sense.

Comment: @MC10 But I had Photo Viewer in Windows 8.1? The PhotoViewer.dll trick worked there.

Comment: @Ramhound That's how it worked in Windows 8.1, I could set it to open with PhotoViewer.dll.

Comment: @Irastris did you see my answer? You can definitely use the dll and photo viewer still works in win 10. Give me that answer credit :D

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't tried that or heard of it. Well if it works, that's great.

Comment: The following `reg` file places Photo Viewer in the list of other programs: 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.jpg]
@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.jpeg]
@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.gif]
@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.png]
@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.bmp]
@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.tiff]
@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.ico]
@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"

Comment: You can get most of the functionality you remember using both Windows Explorer (to print, see http://superuser.com/questions/989145/ ) and the metro photos app.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I think because of your first attempt to run the .dll directly, the entry "Windows Photo Viewer" still points to the .dll instead of rundll32, which of course you can't run directly.

Try adding the following to the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open]
"MuiVerb"="@photoviewer.dll,-3043"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,72,00,75,00,\
6e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,\
00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,\
25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,50,00,68,00,6f,\
00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,50,00,68,00,\
6f,00,74,00,6f,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
00,22,00,2c,00,20,00,49,00,6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,\
5f,00,46,00,75,00,6c,00,6c,00,73,00,63,00,72,00,65,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,25,\
00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open\DropTarget]
"Clsid"="{FFE2A43C-56B9-4bf5-9A79-CC6D4285608A}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\print]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,72,00,75,00,\
6e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,\
00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,\
25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,50,00,68,00,6f,\
00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,50,00,68,00,\
6f,00,74,00,6f,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
00,22,00,2c,00,20,00,49,00,6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,\
5f,00,46,00,75,00,6c,00,6c,00,73,00,63,00,72,00,65,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,25,\
00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\print\DropTarget]
"Clsid"="{60fd46de-f830-4894-a628-6fa81bc0190d}"
```

([Source](http://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/8930-windows-photo-viewer-gone-post290818.html#post290818))

If that doesn't work, try searching the registry for Windows Photo Viewer and photoviewer.dll to see if there are any references to photoviewer.dll being called directly (without rundll32).

Comment: great, it worked.

Comment: It also worked for me, Windows 10 Pro 64 bits, and fr-ch localization. Great !

Comment: The hex string is utf-16 for `%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1"`. I just did a `xxd -r -p | tr -d '\0'` on it.

Comment: This answer nails the problem - it is a 32-bit DLL and so needs to be run with rundll32.  Another option to avoid regedit is to pin something (anything) to the start menu and then edit it so that the shortcut is to %SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen <folder>.

Comment: Windows 10 LTSC worked

Answer (score 25):

I got mine to work, I think you have to successfully open an image with the old photo viewer once, then you can set it as default.

1. Open an image with this in command prompt %SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen *pathToImageNoQuotes*
2. Then I have this option

[image]

Now my PNGs open with the old photo viewer by default, works great.

Comment: This only half worked. :/ Launching PhotoViewer from the Command Prompt worked perfectly, but when I tried to set the PNG to open with Photo Viewer afterward, I still got the "This app can not run on your PC" error.

Comment: awww, I'm sorry. That error is usually x86 x64 issues, running an x64 app on x86 install. Wonder what gives...

Comment: @Irastris which bit version of Windows 10 are you on? There is an x86 path, perhaps that would work for you. `%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen pathToImage`

Comment: @MC10 Windows 10 Pro 64Bit, from the GWX upgrade. :D

Comment: It's working for me with both x86 and x64 DLLs. Try running `sfc /scannow` and see if it finds/fixes anything. Did you try both DLL's?

Comment: @MC10 Yes, I tried both DLLs in CMD, went to a PNG, tried to open with Photo Viewer, and still got the error.

Comment: Strange...and sfc didn't fix anything?

Comment: for me above is working, but I'm not getting step 2. Therefore how do I force it to get step2

Comment: for me, this opens the photo viewer: `%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen`, yet when I add an image path at the end, nothing happens, and no applications opens up.

Answer (score 17):

Put this in a .reg file and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jpegfile\shell\open]
"MuiVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,\
  69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,\
  00,20,00,50,00,68,00,6f,00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,\
  72,00,5c,00,70,00,68,00,6f,00,74,00,6f,00,76,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,\
  00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,33,00,30,00,34,00,33,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jpegfile\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,72,00,75,00,\
  6e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,\
  00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,\
  25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,50,00,68,00,6f,\
  00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,50,00,68,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,6f,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,22,00,2c,00,20,00,49,00,6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,\
  5f,00,46,00,75,00,6c,00,6c,00,73,00,63,00,72,00,65,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,25,\
  00,31,00,00,00
```

This will make all JPEG files viewable in Photo Viewer. If you want to make other types work as well just replace "jpegfile" in the code with "pngfile", "giffile", "Paint.Picture" (Paint.Picture is the .bmp type)

Find any picture, right-click, choose Open With, then find Windows Photo Viewer and select it as default program.

Comment: Didn't work. Still getting the "This app can not run on your PC." error.

Comment: worked fine (y) thx

Answer (score 14):

You can also use [Winaero Tweaker](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.1836) to activate Windows Photo Viewer, as shown in the following screenshot. Just follow the **description** (within the green box), and you're all set.

**PS:** Winaero Tweaker is a free tool, which can be used to tweak many aspects of Windows 10.

[image: Winaero Tweaker - Activate Windows Photo Viewer]

Comment: It's nice to see that WinAero got an update for this.

Comment: This turned out to actually be the easiest solution for me, due to avoiding the Windows Registry Editor.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: It redirects to `Set your default programs` in Control Panel. I don't know if Windows Photo Viewer is visible without Winaero Tweaker though.

Comment: After coming to this page again, I compared what changed before and after Winaero Tweaker. It adds 9 new default extensions on top of the existing ones (`.tif` and `.tiff`).

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution without having to alter the registry. 
I have followed [TechnoCore's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/947672/how-to-bring-back-photo-viewer-in-windows-10/947691#947691), but as the comments indicated, the second part wasn't working for me either.
So this is what to do:

1. Open a command line as administrator
2. Type in the following:

> ```
> >ftype MyFileType=%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll" ImageView_Fullscreen %1
> >assoc .jpg=MyFileType
> ```

3. Then go to the image file and choose open with... and then choose the command you just typed:
   [image]

Make sure you have the "Always use this app..." option checked.
Repeat it for all file types you want to associate with Windows Photo Viewer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, none of the above answers worked for me, but they pointed me in the right direction.

1. Right-click on an image in Windows Explorer, choose `Open With`, then `Choose another app`.
2. In the dialog, scroll down and click on `More apps`, then `Look for another app on this PC.
3. Then, at the bottom right, choose `All Files (*.*)` instead of `Programs (*.exe ...)`, then navigate to `C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer` and choose `PhotoViewer.dll`.
4. Photo Viewer opens. Close it.
5. Repeat Step 1: Right-click again on the image, choose `Open With`, then `Choose another app`.
6. Again scroll down to click on `More apps`.
7. Now Windows Photo Viewer appears in the apps list. Choose it and click on `Always use this app to open .png files`.

Once you did steps 1-4, you don't have to repeat them for other file types. Steps 5-7 should suffice.

Comment: DOESN'T WORK on Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 x64 (clean install) :(. Steps 1-3 *atually* works no problem, and the `.dll` file is there. In fact, now Photo Viewer shows up as an available app as in steps 5-7. However, when I select to use it I get the warning: `This app can't run on your PC, To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher`. tried

Comment: @theforestecologist Yes, it didn't work for me either when I tried it the last time. Two years ago it did, however. The best solution at the moment is Winaero Tweaker.

Answer (score 1):

I didnt care for the other Registry answers, as they were all encoded. Here is
one that is decoded:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpg]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jpegfile\shell\open\command]
@="rundll32.exe \"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\",ImageView_Fullscreen %1"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pngfile\shell\open\command]
@="rundll32.exe \"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\",ImageView_Fullscreen %1"
```

If your `%ProgramFiles%` is not `C:\Program Files`, then adjust as needed.