# Preview photos in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

So in windows 7, you could see the photo thumbnails before you clicked on a photo to open it. Now, in windows 10, all you get is this:

[image]

So in order for me to find a picture, I have to double click it and hope to find it. Is there a way to enable a preview of some sort so I can quickly find what I need?(Just like on windows 7 where it showed the picture)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer you said helped as the answer. :)

Comment: Please mark the answer below as the answer. It worked for me.. ;)

Answer (score 36):

In Windows Explorer, go to the View Menu > Options > View Tab, and deselect "Always show icons, never thumbnails"

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is just retarded problem. I cant believe if this comes as default.

Comment: does it affect performance.

Comment: In my Windows 10, View is a tab with a ribbon and Options is a menu on the far right of the ribbon.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't changed any settings yet I see the icons. Try clearing your thumbnail cache. Search **Disk Cleanup** in Start/search bar and open it. Check **Thumbnails** and click OK.

[image: Disk Cleanup]

If that does not fix it, [rebuild your icon cache](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-icon-cache-rebuild-windows-10-a.html). I would also recommend restarting your computer after trying these options.

Comment: I've tried everything, even went on the 'rebuild your icon cache' site, restarted etc, nothing works :(

Answer (score 3):

1. hit the `VIEW` tab
2. hit `OPTIONS`
3. hit `PREVIEW PANE`

[image]

Comment: this doesn't answer the question,  but it answers the question I came here for which is also helpful for people. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try right-click on any image -> Properties -> Change(around the top at the right) -> try changing it to photo gallery or windows photo viewer

Comment: I only 'Photos', 'Microsoft Office Picture Manager' , 'Paint' and look for another app on this pc. :(

Comment: Try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/947672/how-to-bring-back-photo-viewer-in-windows-10) to get back Photo Viewer. Then try setting the default app to Photo Viewer and clear/rebuild caches.

Comment: windows photo viewer is not availabe for me too.. I like the way windows 7 showed photos. Hate windows 10.. except that microsoft forced me to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: right-click on the folder and select **View > Large icons**.

Comment: It's already viewed at 'Large Icons' :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the file folder icon at the bottom of your screen in the taskbar to open File Explorer.
2. Click on *View* in the File Explorer toolbar in the top of the window in that application.
3. On the right side click *Options*.
4. Click on *Change folder and search options*.
5. Click on the *View* tab in the new pop-up *Options* window that comes up.
6. Click on *Apply to folders*.
7. Uncheck *Always show icons, never thumbnails*. Stupidly this is the Windows 10 default setting.
8. Click *Apply*, then *OK*.