# Pictures thumbnail not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, thumbnails, pictures

I have this problem since a while now and can't find any solutions.
This one is not working [Preview photos in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/951955/preview-photos-in-windows-10/)

I've tried to delete the thumbnails in any ways, but still no result.

Also, when I go to *Quick Access* or *This PC*, I'm stuck on *Working on it…*, and last but not least, when I try to open the properties of any file or folder, nothing happen.

Did someone had this problem and find a fix? Thanks.

Comment: "when I try to open the properties of any file or folder, nothing happen." - sounds like you have massive system integrity issue I would either Reset your system or reinstall WIndows 10.  You are using Build 10240 correct?

Comment: Yes, _10240_. I had a bunch of fail while migrating from W8 like impossible to connect my mMcrosoft account, the button _Link to Microsoft account_ wouldn't work, but it's fine now.

Comment: Just made an update (didn't remember what they were) and seems to find back everything. However, the file's properties are very slow to appear (4s) that close to the time my computer need to boot…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preview photos in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/951955/preview-photos-in-windows-10)

Comment: The linked answer may be better for others having the title issue, but OPs particular issue is more likely due to significant disk issues.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Windows photos app in Powershell paste
(To remove Photos app from current account only)
`Get-AppxPackage *photo* | Remove-AppxPackage`