# Print multiple photos in Windows 10 like the old Photo Viewer app could in old Windows 7 / Vista / XP

Tags: windows-10, printing, images, photos, pictures

Trying to print multiple pictures / photos / images from the Windows Photos app. Printing from here only allows one photo per printed page.

I want to be able to control which photos to print and at what size, including a "contact sheet" with as many pictures as possible per printed page to save paper -- like you used to be able to in the old Photo Viewer / Print Pictures modal dialog in older versions of Windows.

This also has to be in a way that I can explain to a non-technical person over the phone (my Mum).

Options I have considered but don't really want to do:

- Hack the registry to [bring back Windows Photo Viewer](https://superuser.com/questions/947672/how-to-bring-back-photo-viewer-in-windows-10) - not suitable for luddites
- Create a Word document with the photos in and print that - do-able, but not quick, easy, intuitive or repeatable.

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft moved the cheese! I kicked myself when I found out how to do this oh-so-simple task. I had expected to be able to do this from the Metro-style "Photos" app ... but no!

### tldr; / Summary

In Windows Explorer, select the images to print then right click one and select `print` from context menu.

### Full explanation with pictures

Open the folder containing the photos you want to print in Windows Explorer, then select the few you want using the normal methods:

- Dragging over them
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left Mouse Click to select multiple individual ones
- Focus on a picture using keyboard arrow keys and select images using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> (individual) or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> (range)

[image: Detail of windows explorer window showing selected photos]

Then print them using one of the following:

- Right Click (click with right-hand mouse button) one of the selected photos and choose `print` from the context menu that appears
- Click the context menu key some keyboards have (usually box with three lines - a burger) to bring up the menu with the print option
- choose `print` from the `Share` ribbon menu options

This then shows the print control you will recognize from your old windows days:

[image: View of Windows 10 print dialog showing multiple photos per page]

Choose how to print them and you're golden.