# Using Windows 10, how do I view a really tall stack of photos as a single jpg?

Tags: windows-10, jpeg

So I got a jpg image file, which looks like a long sequence of individual images in sequence and saved a single file.

When I open up the file to look at it in the Windows "Photos" app, all I see is a very tall and thin image too small to see anything. When I zoom in, I can see one or two of the images in the stack, but I can't vertical scroll..

The person who sent me the photo said, "It works just fine on a Mac."

Considering that "It works fine on a Mac" is a non-answer, how can I view this image type on Windows? The file type is a jpg, but other than that, I don't even know what to call this image type. I've tried searching for solutions in Google, but I haven't found anything remotely close to this topic.

Comment: You should seriously consider [reactivating Photo Viewer](https://superuser.com/q/947672/219095). It’s superior to the the Photos app anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image exceeds the capabilities of the Photos app, or the image is greater
than the amount of available RAM (unlikely).

I would suggest getting a better and more efficient image editor/viewer.

My recommendation would be to try first the excellent and free
[Paint.NET](https://www.getpaint.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't a permanent solution, it's easy and doesn't require installing anything. From Windows Explorer, drag the file into Chrome browser window. (I didn't test this against any other browsers.) I still had to zoom in, but I had vertical scrolling capability.