Windows calculator launches only on the third try
Update
After five or six weeks, the problem went away and has not recurred since.  I have not hypothesis for what might have changed to fix it.

Original Post
Since the May 2024 patches for Windows 10, launching Calculator is no longer reliable.  Does anyone recognize this problem and have a fix?

The first attempt will bring up a window with the calculator icon on a blue background.  Often (but not always) that window has the minimize, maximize, and close buttons.  But that's it.  There's nothing to do but close it.


The second attempt (apparently) does nothing.

The third attempt succeeds in bringing up a functional calculator.



Subsequent attempts will work as expected, for a while.  But if I don't call up the calculator for a period of time—say, an hour—I'll be back at step 1.
I haven't found anything relevant in the Event Viewer.  This is on Windows 10 Pro after applying the 2024-05-14 patches.
More Debugging
I used Sysinternals Process Monitor to capture events related to the calculator while starting up.

This first thing I learned is that there are two executables: calc.exe runs first, and it gets sihost.exe to launch CalculatorApp.exe.  Both processes live on until the application is closed.

It's a Heisenbug:  The problem has never occurred while Process Monitor is watching.  But if I shut down Process Monitor or just turn off its capture mode, the problem returns.



Try performing a reset on the application.

@Ramhound:  Where is that setting?  If I choose "Settings" from the Calculator's system menu, I don't see anything like what you're link shows.

Another option is to reinstall the old Calculator executable, rather than the MS 'app' version. (I've done so because the app is slow to start, far slower than the original.) See https://winaero.com/get-calculator-from-windows-8-and-windows-7-in-windows-10/, https://superuser.com/questions/1340199/how-to-bring-back-the-old-windows-7-calculator-in-windows-10

@DrMoishePippik - That doesn’t actually solve the authors problem

A reset on the application made no difference.  But I appreciate the suggestion. That was worth trying.

If performing a Reset does it work uninstall the application and reinstall it from the Microsoft Store.

@Ramhound, it certainly does, unless the OP has some reason to prefer the app version. It is not an answer, but a viable workaround.

@Ramhound:  Hmm.  I've never visited the Microsoft Store.  I was under the impression that required a Microsoft account, which I'm opposed to.  But I see claims that it can be done without an account.  I guess I'll have to look into that.

The only other choice you have to the Microsoft Store would be to perform an in-place install of Windows in it’s entirety, entirely up to you, I consider just reinstalling a single application appropriate.

There's other calculators. Another one.

@Ramhound I'm seeing the same exact issue with two PCs that had no issues. I'm a power user. When I started seeing the issue in the first PC, I reformatted my drive and reinstalled the latest version of Windows 10 Pro from zero. After install, I updated everything on Windows Update. Had not installed software other than Office Professional Plus 2021. And the issue was there. Then I noticed the issue in another one of my PCs with way more powerful hardware and specs (almost new). I'm suspecting this comes from a recent Windows update. Even wondering if MS is breaking Windows 10 on purpose.

@FranciscoZarabozo - It absolutely is not from a recent Windows Update.

I’m voting to close this question because it's no longer reproducible and thus it's impossible to collect more data to find the root cause.

One thing I've just noticed is that the issue happens only when opening the calculator with the calculator button on a Microsoft keyboard (specifically, the Microsoft Wireless Confort Keyboard 5050). If I instead open it from start menu, the issue doesn't happen at all.
