# Change background colour of Windows 10's Photos

Tags: windows-10, photos, windows-photo-viewer

When viewing an image in Windows 7's Photo Viewer, it would have a coloured background that made it clear where the image started and ended. By comparison, in Windows 10, the background is always white when viewing an image with Windows Photos. As someone who works with a lot of images with white backgrounds, and often relies on the image viewer a lot to make important design decisions, this is very problematic.

Is there any way to change Photos' default background colour from white to something else? Note that I'm not simply asking to bring back Photo Viewer, which I know [can be done](https://superuser.com/questions/947672/how-to-bring-back-photo-viewer-in-windows-10), but it feels hacky and unstable to force legacy software to run on a modern OS, and it seems that it would be less trouble to just change Photos' background colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the background black by checking "Dark Mode" in settings.